# System.Transactions.TransactionScope missing function "new()"

Tags: .net, powershell, transactions, transactionscope

I am using PowerShell to test out AlphaFS a little. 
Whilst on my Windows 10 dev env this line runs just fine:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator [System.Transactions.TransactionScope]::new([System.Transactions.TransactionScopeOption]::Re
uiresNew)
```

An exception is thrown on a Windows Server 2012 R2.

```
Method invocation failed because [System.Transactions.TransactionScope] does not contain a method named 'new'.
At line:1 char:1
+ [System.Transactions.TransactionScope]::new([System.Transactions.TransactionScop ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

Only Methods that could be used are ::Equals() and ::ReferenceEquals().
I could not get any information on that function and where it belongs to. Do I need to install a specific .NET Framework to get this to work?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `::new()` static constructor invocation method was first introduced in **PowerShell 5.0**.

Windows Server 2012 R2 ships with PowerShell 4.0

For pre-5.0 compatibility, use [`New-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-object) instead:

```
$transScope = New-Object System.Transactions.TransactionScope -ArgumentList ([System.Transactions.TransactionScopeOption]::RequiresNew)
```